# How to create a caster wheel (Urdf model)

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built a 2 wheel robot and I have been trying for hours to put a correct caster wheel on it. I followed the logic of this [code](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/blob/master/chapter_2_codes/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/urdf/diff_wheeled_robot.urdf) in which a sphere with a fixed joint is used and I managed to make it work (or I thought so) until I commanded my robot to move. The movement was totally wrong. With the fixed joint sphere, the robot was bumping like crazy. Is there another way to create a caster wheel ?

Thanks for answering and for your time in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240717/how-to-create-a-caster-wheel-(urdf-model)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the bumping of the robot by increasing the weight of the base_link. Now the movement seems smooth.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vinit_sarode](https://answers.ros.org/users/29742/vinit_sarode/) on 2017-03-19**:
Adding mass in base_link has solved my problem of bumping or jerky motion of robot.
Thank you.